# Rendering in 3.0

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I am just getting back into learning blender again. In the version I was on previously it had a option called blender render which was ideal for me as my laptop has a onboard graphics card and cycles was unusable on it.

Is that no longer an option in blender 3.0?

I currently do not have the cash to put into a better computer but hopefully in the future I will.

Comment: By any chance, could you be referring to "Eevee"? Which version were you using previously?

Comment: I think you are talking about "Blender Internal" which was phased out after 2.79 and replaced with EEVEE. If that is incompatible with your GPU (unlikely), you can still use _workbench_, but you might find some features rather limited.

Comment: Thank you, yes I was using version 2.79 previously. I know in cycles my onboard graphics card was not supported in that version. I will look into workbench if I have issues. Thank You.